# Having a Batch script print network contents in small files

Tags: batch-file, printing

I have a script that prints all contents on the network into local text files.
I need to adjust this script, so that each output file is maximum 10 mb large.

So far the script looks like this:

```
::@ECHO OFF
echo %date% %time%  Starting %~dp0

set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set hour=%time:~0,2%
set minute=%time:~3,2%
set second=%time:~6,2%
set folderName=%year%-%month%-%day%-%hour%-%minute%-%second%
set folderName=%folderName: =%
SET logger="%~dp0"\%folderName%.log

::Loop igjennom alle folders på nettverket, alfabetisk. Print ut innholdet i hver mappe, med full path.

set "list=N:\ O:\ P:\ R:\ V:\ Y:\ Z:\"
FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO (
    SET project=%%i & call :project
)

:project
echo Printing from %project% >> %logger%
set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set hour=%time:~0,2%
set minute=%time:~3,2%
set second=%time:~6,2%
set folderName=%year%-%month%-%day%-%hour%-%minute%-%second%
set folderName=%folderName: =%
SET logger="%~dp0"\%folderName%.log
dir /b /a-d /s %project% > %logger%
```

The best would likely be to do a file size check prior to every folder print, like this:

```
:folder
echo Printing from %folder% >> %logger%
if (LogfileSize > 10mb) then Logfile=new Logfile.
Print folder to Logfile.
```

I just don't know how to write this in batch. **How do I adjust the script to run :folder prior to printing any folder?**

Comment: what you mean with print? Printing to console or sending to a printer?

Comment: "prints all contents on the network into local text files"

Answer (score 0):

you can get the filesize with `for`. But the numbers may get bigger than `cmd` can use them as numbers, so you have to use string comparison instead.

```
for %%i in (%logger%) do set "size=0000000000%%~zi"
set size=%size:~-10%
if %size% gtr 0010485760 echo more than 10MB
```

Obviously, you should compare to a number less than 10MB, if you want to add something an still stay below 10MB (how much less depends on your data)